# How to set the value of DateTimePicker in DataGridView to Null?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have added a `DateTimePicker` in `DataGridView` and I want to set the value of it to `null`
when loaded but it shows the Date now. Is there a way to do it because if it just a `DateTimePicker` Tool it is possible.

Here is how I declare it:

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
```

Then I add it in my `DataGridView`:

```
dgStock.Controls.Add(dtp);
```

I wanted to input The `ExpirationDate` of a product in the `dtp` but some products don't have `ExpirationDate`.
So I wanted to do when I load the data in the `dgStock`, the `dtp` should be `null` by default.

Comment: _"because if it just a DateTimePicker Tool it is possible"_ How?

Comment: Consider setting the `ShowCheckBox` property to true. Then, you can just toggle the `Checked` property.

Comment: @41686d6564 `dtp.CustomFormat = " ";` but when i tried this in the `DateTimePicker` in my `DataGridView`, it just wont change a thing.

Comment: @41686d6564 okay sir ill try it.

Comment: @41686d6564 still wont change a thing